# Developing a SIP based VOIP softphone for integration in web application

Tags: javascript, node.js, sip, voip

I am developing a web application on the stack:

node.js (reverse proxied by nginx)
backbone.js
mongodb

The application has forms containing phone number fields. A button at the end of the application is required to call that number.
Our service provided of SIP gave us these:

1. sip:phone_number@some.host.ip
2. username
3. password

Now, i was exploring options and came across phono.com, sipml5 and asterisk (for server)

Do we really need a asterisk or freeswitch server for this? I am in a notion that what i require is just a frontend library that allows to make calls using SIP account details provided. The interface (dialing pad etc.) can be developed though by making neat API calls with the library.

I found sipml5 un-necessarily complicated. phonojs doesn't work. What are my options in this case?

Please shed some light over the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's not required to use Asterisk. Though, you will need something that understands websocket, since all signaling from web-based clients usually goes through that type of connection.

In your case you can use something like [OverSIP](http://oversip.net/documentation/1.4.x/overview/) proxy to pass SIP from your web-client over to your service provider. Or you can try to search for a carrier that provides WebRTC service, like [vLine](https://vline.com/)

Comment: how do i go ahead with vLine? Its a video platform.

Comment: what exactly not clear about it? It's a platform that provides WebRTC. Refer to [documentation](https://vline.com/developer/).

Comment: i went through the docs and i am still clueless :( I need something like phono.com

Comment: well it seems they do not support calling to PSTN. So you can use OverSIP to proxy your 'SIP via Websocket' traffic or you can use Asterisk (or FreeSWITCH, or whatever) as a B2BUA.

Comment: can you illustrate the process? I am actually a noob in this stuff.

Comment: The simplest scheme is that you establish a Websocket connection to your Asterisk box and placing a call using SIP (that sends over that websocket connection). Your Asterisk box in its turn will (by the means of dialplan) establish a call to your service provider. After that you send RTP, using webrtc, again to your Asterisk which will relay it to your provider. That's how B2BUA works.

Comment: in the very first line of your answer you have said that asterisk isn't required. Will you be able to share your email address?

Comment: that depends on what you want

Comment: just wanted to chat regarding this.

Comment: you can ask a question here, and I would answer it. I'm afraid I don't have time for private consulting on this.

Comment: No problem! can you elaborate the process you suggested in terms of javascript? I am using backbone.js as MV* on frontend. I need to know a starting point on this.

Comment: try to read sipml5 documentation. They have some nice examples there.